# Flower with small, intensely blue blooms

Tags: identification, flowers

What is this flower, with small (diameter approx. 1 cm), intensely blue blooms and as encountered on a hot mid-summer day in Central Europe?

[image]

Comment: Specifically, this one is Lobelia erinus pendula 'sapphire' https://www.shootgardening.co.uk/plant/lobelia-erinus-pendula-sapphire usually sold as Lobelia sapphire trailing (as opposed to bush, which is upright)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Lobelia erinus, but most of the time I have just seen it called Lobelia, even though there seem to be other species in the genus Lobelia which look quite different.